# Fastest way to connect to PHP file from C#

Tags: c#, php, sockets, webrequest

I am developing a turn-based game in C# that uses a PHP server. I have created a series of small PHP scripts that do all the necessary server processing. I am trying to determine the fastest way to connect to these scripts. Obviously, I can just use a `WebRequest` to execute the script, but I was wondering if using sockets would result in a faster transfer, ignoring the time it takes to execute the script.

Should I use `WebRequest` (simple), or use sockets (more complicated)?

Comment: you'll be using tcp no matter what you end up using anyways.

Comment: True. But using sockets would allow me to use any port and not use the crowded port 80.

Comment: `WebRequest` isn't limited to port 80/443. You can use any port like `http://example.com:8080`

Comment: Doubt it makes it much faster to write your own socket code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: the WebRequest object already has all the code you need to communicate with a web server application.  As long as your PHP code is being served up by a web server, the WebRequest is your best option.  You could write a bunch of code using Socket objects to communicate with your web server, but you would wind up spending a lot of time writing a half-baked WebRequest object.